# Returning the address or value of the second byte of an int

Tags: c, pointers

I have an int declared and assigned a value in c. In memory it looks like the following

**0x78 0x01 0x00 0x00  at address 0x20002AD4**

I need to extract the values from the first and second byte of the int. I have successfully extracted the first byte with the following code (see packet[2])

```
int dataSize = (lightCount * 3) + 1;
unsigned char packet[totalSize];

packet[0] = 0x7E;
packet[1] = 0x06;
packet[2] = (unsigned char)*(&dataSize); //dataSize LSB - THIS WORKS
packet[3] = (unsigned char)*(&dataSize + 1); //dataSize MSB - THIS DOES NOT
```

However, when I try and use pointer arithmetic to return the value for the second byte in the int (see packet[3]), it instead returns the 4th byte along. I believe this is due to the fact that ints are 4 bytes in size, so a +1 on an address moves 4 bytes along.

Can anyone suggest how I can return the value in the second byte, i.e. in the example above I want to return 0x01

Comment: Be careful about Endianness.

Comment: You have to cast the pointer to char, not the pointer to int. Try `((unsigned char *)&dataSize)[0]` (or 1, respectively).

Comment: @Acme That's not the source of the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full sample program of the code given (modified to get the second part of the byte):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int dataSize = 0x7E06;
    unsigned char packet[4];

    packet[0] = 0x7E;
    packet[1] = 0x06;
    packet[2] = (unsigned char)dataSize;
    packet[3] = *(((unsigned char*)&dataSize) + 1);

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", packet[0], packet[1], packet[2], packet[3]);
}
```

On my computer, this will output `126, 6, 6, 126`. On other architectures, the bytes may be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to address the elements of the *char* array, not treat the int as an array:

```
unsigned char const * p = (unsigned char const *)&dataSize;

packet[2] = p[0];
packet[3] = p[1];
```